# How to insert an array in MySQL table with Laravel ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to insert an entire api response into a MySQL table using Laravel Eloquent but I am getting 'Array to string conversion' error. How do I solve this?

Please note, it is compulsory that I save the entire API response.

My API call

```
$response = Curl::to($url.$request->account_number)
                    ->withData($data)
                    ->asJson(true)
                    ->get();
```

My Query

```
 TransactionLog::create([
                        'payer' => $request->payer,
                        'amount' => $request->amount,
                        'phone' => $request->phone,
                        'response' => $response

                    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you using [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl) ?

With `asJson(true)` you will receive `json_decode` response, so if your plan is to save raw json response in the database you'll have to `json_encode` it like:

```
TransactionLog::create([
  'payer' => $request->payer,
  'amount' => $request->amount,
  'phone' => $request->phone,
  'response' => json_encode($response)
]);
```